# Scipy CSR matrix Element-wise Division

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, division

Is there any methods in CSR implementation for element-wise division? By doing A/B of 2 CSR matrixes of the same shape, gives me a memory error. Can someone please help?

Comment: If B has even a single zero entry, that's going to lead to division by 0.

Comment: Please check [ask] and make your question a [mcve] .

Comment: *"... gives me a memory error."*   0/0 results in `nan`, so the result of `A/B` is not sparsely populated.  It is full of `nan` values, along with `inf` where `A` is nonzero but `B` is zero, and those values must be stored in memory.